Github Go To File and Chrome Search engine
Is there a way to setup search terms in chrome so that it pulls up a github repo and auto populates the Find File text with the search term?
I've even tried inspecting the html to see if it was an easily retrievable and modifiable tag but had no luck.

Yes. Here is a guide on how to do that.
Create a Chrome search shortcut for your GitHub Repo
Instructions

Open Chrome > Settings
Search "manage search engines" and click into it
Click "Add"



Give "search engine" a name. e.g GitHub - Some repo
Give "keyword" a shortcut e.g gh
Give "URL with %s in place of query" the URL below:

https://github.com/search?q=%s+repo%3A[ORG]%2F[REPO]&type=Code

Replace `[ORG]` with your organisation/username and `[REPO]` with the name of your repository.

e.g for Django:

https://github.com/search?q=%s+repo%3Adjango%2Fdjango&type=Code



Click "Add".

Search! e.g Type "gh NameOfComponent" in your address bar.


Source: https://gist.github.com/djm/0a43f7dee02a2acca4b3894d0b349990
Thanks to David Winterbottom (@codeinthehole). See https://twitter.com/codeinthehole/status/1346774847221870593
